# spring web flow transition on attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I try understand how spring web flow works. I know that. I make a flow in separate file.xml with flow definition something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

   <view-state id="hello" view="/jsp/smp/wzory/wzory">
       <transition on="next" to="nextView"/>
   </view-state>

   <end-state id="nextView" view="/jsp/smp/wzory/next"/>
```

Here i have two views

- hello (/jsp/smp/wzory/wzory.jsp)
- nextView (/jsp/smp/wzory/next.jsp)

And now i would like go from view hello to view nextView. This operation i would like trigger after clicking to hyperlink a href="" But what a mean that expression

```
  transition on="next"
```

what exacly is that on, on what?

```
http://localhost:8080/next
 <a href="http://localhost:8080/next"
```

or something variable have to be pass to hyperlink to inform spring webflow to go to the next view-state?

```
 <a href="http://localhost:8080/somePage?on=next"
```

Answer (score 1):

that `on` is `eventId` see example bellow (it's Spring Web Flow and Thymeleaf code)

```
<a th:href="@{${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId='next')}">Next page</a>
```

And don't forget `flowExecutionUrl`